# Responsive design - reverse css effect between the mobile & desktop layout in this case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the present case, the menu is expanded in desktop layout and the menu  is hided in mobile layout.

My question is how to make it below?

- mobile layout : no hide & expand the menu
- desktop layout : hide the    menu

```js
$('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
  $('nav').toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
#top-bar {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #22bbff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
#nav-toggle {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px solid #fff;
}
nav {
  float: right;
}
.active ul {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  top: 60px;
  right: 0;
  width: 150px;
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #22bbff;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
}
li {
  display: block;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 21px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #294C52;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #1BBC9B;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  nav {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    right: 50%;
  }
  #nav-toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  ul {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    right: -50%;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: none;
  }
  li {
    float: left;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="top-bar">
  <a href="#" id="nav-toggle">M</a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link 2 <i></i></a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want the reverse of what you have?

Comment: try to build it with bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all add this

```
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

since you want to make it responsive... 
so how about to use it 
for example

```
   <body>

<div class="container">
      <h2>Table</h2>
      <p>The .table-responsive class creates a responsive table which will scroll horizontally on small devices (under 768px). When viewing on anything larger than 768px wide, there is no difference:</p>                                                                                      
      <div class="table-responsive">          
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Firstname</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Anna</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Debbie</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>John</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
```

so if you leave a class or another container out side "table-responsive" of this container it is just not going to be responsive anymore...

Comment: Although bootstrap isn't bad, it isn't the sollution to every css problem, nor the sollution to the OPs question

Comment: First of all bootstrap has good documentation, it is updated more often than any responsive library support, it has base styling for most HTML elements, it has extensive list of components... if you know a better solution let me know also...
at the end we try to help to each other ... criticism just for criticism is useless @Kiwi

Comment: @Kiwi well unless if you are not french or belgian :D

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to make the reverse of your example — small collapsed menu on ordinary browsers, full menu on mobile — you can change your @media query from using `min-width` to this:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Lgpyjgw3/). This will break the menu’s layout when the viewport becomes too narrow, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could always just reverse your css styles applied to desktop views & targeted media queries as I have done below using your original css.

You will need to customise your css for the dropdown menu in desktop view (the current view is probably not want you want, though the behaviour is correct). You can do this with additional css classes. Just check your browser console for guidance.

```js
$('#nav-toggle').click(function() {
  $('nav').toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}
#top-bar {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 85px;
  background-color: #22bbff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 50%;
}
#nav-toggle {
  display: none;
}
ul {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: -50%;
  width: auto;
  height: 60px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: none;
}
li {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 21px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 21px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #294C52;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
a:hover {
  background-color: #1BBC9B;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
  #nav-toggle {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
  }
  nav {
    float: right;
  }
  .active ul {
    display: block;
  }
  ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    top: 60px;
    right: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: #22bbff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
  li {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="top-bar">
  <a href="#" id="nav-toggle">M</a>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Link 2 <i></i></a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```